# XMLHttpRequest ERROR in Flutter web application during API call

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, flutter-web, flutter-http

This issue has stopped me in my tracks.

```js
Error: XMLHttpRequest error.
    C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/patch/core_patch.dart 910:28                get current
packages/http/src/browser_client.dart 69:22                                                                                    <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/zone.dart 1685:54                                              runUnary
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 159:18                                        handleValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 766:44                                        handleValueCallback
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 795:13                                        _propagateToListeners
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/future_impl.dart 592:7                                         [_complete]
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream_pipe.dart 61:11                                         _cancelAndValue
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/async/stream.dart 1288:7                                             <fn>
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 334:14  _checkAndCall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/_internal/js_dev_runtime/private/ddc_runtime/operations.dart 339:39  dcall
C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/out/host_debug/dart-sdk/lib/html/dart2js/html_dart2js.dart 37301:58                              <fn>
```

. I have tried deleting the cache tool stamp file. Adding "--disable-web-security". This is my method that is throwing the error when called.

```js
Future CustomerCall(String CustomerID, String APIKey) async {
  final queryParameters = {
    'APIKey': APIKey,
    'customer_id': CustomerID
  };

  final uri = Uri.https('8.8.8.8', '/Customers', queryParameters);
  final response = await http.get(uri, headers: {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
  });

  print(response.statusCode);
  print(response.body);
}
```

. When I replace the local host IP with something like "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1". It works just fine. I am not sure if its because of the port number being in the URL or if it possibly could be because the page does not have a SSL cert but is under a HTTPS rather than a HTTP. This is an API call to this URL for another application we have made for users to transfer data from a windows application the a web application.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must be handle this issue from server side

actually in api side must be configure CORS mechanism

Comment: Is this in the API application itself or is it in the server configuration

Comment: Api application,
it is Django?